# Specify a password when opening an FTP address in windows explorer

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

Does anyone know how I can specify a password when opening an ftp address in explorer from the command line?

Along the lines of:

```
explorer -pw foo ftp://bar@foo.bar.com
```

Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can login using he following command

```
explorer.exe user:password@ftpsite.com
```

Comment: +1'd, but don't forget the "ftp://"... i.e., "explorer.exe ftp ://user:pass@ftpaddress.com"